# Jquery Math.round give wrong result for Negative value

Tags: javascript

I am facing issue in roundoff the negative value
i have write Math.round(-1.5) it gives me result -1 but when i write in Sql Select ROUND(-1.5,0) it gives me -2 result same in C#
but it in Jquery get wrong result any one please help me how to get perfect result in jquery roundoff .

C#,SQl,Excel gives same result but in Jquery give wrong result when value with -0.5
only problem in Negative Value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI8hB.png)

Comment: That's the way `Math.round()` works. It rounds towards 0, except in the case of exactly `.5` as the fraction, in which case it rounds towards positive infinity regardless of the sign of the source value.

Comment: Where does jquery come in? Math.round is a javascript function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: CharlieWallace, Pointy  can you please tell me which is a same question. we have issue with -0.5 you can try and check it what happen in -0.5 and 0.5 in Math.round function. i have checked there is no duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can write yourself a function to "fix" the native behavior:

```js
    function signedRound(n) {
      let neg = n < 0 ? -1 : 1;
      return Math.round(Math.abs(n)) * neg;
    }


console.log(signedRound(-1.5));
```

Comment: Thank you it is working